# Bootstrap Toggle with Angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap toggle add on in a project (http://www.bootstraptoggle.com) that is based on AngularJS.  The structure that uses the component is roughly as so:

```
   <parent-directive>
      <tr ng-repeat="myObject in dataSource">
         <child-directive>
            <input id="myToggleButton" data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox">
```

I've narrowed down the problem to the requirement of the bootstrap toggle needing a jQuery selector to initialize the control when it's dynamically created.  The call looks something like this:

```
   $('#myToggleButton').bootstrapToggle();
```

I've tried to add this selector to the 'post' compile event in my directive but the selector does not appear to be valid:

```
        post: function (scope, element, attributes, controller, transcludeFn) {
            $('#myToggleButton').bootstrapToggle();
```

I've added it to a button handler (just to test) which I manually clicked and magically it works.  There is clearly some point in which the compile post event is fired but jQuery is not functional and then at some point when regular user operations start where it is.

Unfortunately, the control seems to require this selector to initialize and the rows of data that hold this switch are built on the fly and not immediately when the page loads.

My question is at what point can a jQuery selector work after a compile function is completed for a directive?  I'm also not supply a link function with I'm guessing I'm going to need as well since this function does change the DOM when it's called.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't repeat ID's in a page, they are unique by definition, convert to class instead.

You should have no problem initializing plugins inside `link` function of directive. If you are using jQuery properly with angular you will have jQuery loaded prior to angular.js so that `angular.element` uses jQuery instead of jQlite.

Then you can do:

```
link:function(scope,elem, attrs){
   elem.find('.myToggleButtonClass').bootstrapToggle({/* options*/});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the post on the link function.  It pointed me in the right direction.  I was already generating the id's dynamically.  I just removed them from the original post to try and simplify the question.  It's definitely a little slower but happy to see if work and definitely understand link functions a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

After the elem.append, the jQuery selector worked like a charm.

```
    template: '<div toggleTag="test"></div>',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, controller, transclude) {
        elem.append('<input id="' + scope.toggleId + '" checked data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox">');
        $('#' + scope.toggleId).bootstrapToggle();
    },
```